# Install pip mininet in macOS

Tags: python, macos, mininet

in my recent project I have to run mininet.I have macOS as host, ubuntu as virtual machine in parallel desktop. Mininet doesn't support macOS. So

Is there any way to install mininet packages via pip in macOS so the IDE can do auto-complementation which will definitely speed up my work. Then run the python script in ubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to install the Python package and not expect it to actually function properly, you can do that:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/mininet/mininet.git
```